# QTPropertyAnimation not finishing properly

Tags: qt, animation

I want to have a button with a click event that opens a frame with an animation.
After I upgraded to QT 5 Beta 2, the frame just stopped at the end, leaving a thin line.

[image: before-during-after]

I have a QProperty animation and each time I click the button I do this:

```
if(this->isOpen) {
    this->animation->setStartValue(this->openRect);
    this->animation->setEndValue(this->closedRect);
} else {
    this->animation->setStartValue(this->closedRect);
    this->animation->setEndValue(this->openRect);
}
this->isOpen = !this->isOpen;

this->animation->start();
```

`openRect` (300x300) and `closedRect` (0x100) are set in the init and are never changed.

Does anybody know what's happening??

EDIT

when I click outside the window, the little line disappears

Comment: what about minimal size?

Comment: Widgets in Qt have minimal size. You can't resize it under given minimal size. You can manipulate minimal size of widgets. Thats why you may get your frame resized like that on Close

Comment: I set the minimumsize to 0,0. But no result

Comment: I noticed that when I click outside the window, that the little bar disappears!