# QT UI only repaints after blur

Tags: qt, animation, user-interface, repaint

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [QTPropertyAnimation not finishing properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13583748/qtpropertyanimation-not-finishing-properly)

I have a UI and after a close animation, a little bar remains.
This bar only goes away if you leave the window.
How do I make sure the bar goes away after the animation?

[image: init-open-close]

Comment: Why did you create new question instead of updating your old question? Try hiding animated widget after animation finishes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming nothing should be displayed at the end of the animation, the best would be to force the window to repaint itself, using `update()` when the animation ends.

If you are returning to the main event loop, this will execute correctly. If not, call `qApp->processEvents()`. Just remember to call this method at the main thread.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Yes this was the solution. I was more hoping to find the cause, but this will do. Thanks!

Comment: Nice! Post some code snippets and we may be able to figure out the cause.